# How to return a boolean in a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Inside submitButton event, I would like to check if there are any users registered or not.

Suppose there are 5 users registered:

```
 getUsers = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(5);
      reject(0);
    });
  }
```

Inside the checkregisteredUsers, I call getUsers and then I check if there are any users. If there are any users, then return true, otherwise false. I set state of UsersFound.

```
  checkRegisteredUsers = () => {
    return this.getUsers().then(result => {
      return this.setState({ UsersFound: result > 0 ? true : false };
    }).catch(reason => {
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }
```

Now, inside the function submitButton, I would like to check for true or false, if there were users registered.

```
submitButton = () => {
      this.checkRegisteredUsers().then(result => {
      this.setState({ UsersFound: result > 0 ? true : false });
    });

    if(!this.state.UsersFound){
    return; **//exit code here and the rest of the code below should not execute and show the dialog box**
    }
    // run some other code
  }
```

When I call submitButton, the state of UsersFound is not set yet. If I click a second time then it is set.
How can I set it inside a promise? Or How can I check for true/false inside the submitButton using promises?

**EDIT:**

The question is: how can I return a boolean from a promise as I would like to check something like this:

```
submitButton = () => {
 if(this.checkRegisteredUsers()){
  return; //the rest of the code below should not execute
}
 //if check users is true then the code below should not execute
 // some other code
}
```

**I don't want a promise returned, I want a boolean.**

Comment: Put the logic inside then

Comment: remove the `then`  and `catch` callback from the `checkRegisteredUsers` method. 
I recommend using `asyn/await` statements to handle async functions as well.

Comment: are you suggesting like this:   `checkRegisteredUsers = () => {
    return this.getUsers();
  }`

I still can't set the state of userChecks. it still returns false the first time I click on the button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: You cannot make a function that returns a promise return a boolean. If you have some asynchronous action (like a fetch to get users from some service), that is inherently asynchronous. You cannot have such a function return a boolean, because by the time the function itself ends, you don't have the information to return true or false.

The closest you can get to that is using async/await. But async functions still only return `Promise` objects. You can make it look different using async/await, but it is just syntactic sugar. You are still effectively running all of the code after the `await` as though it were a function passed to `then`.

As an example, this:

```
//Some function that will resolve or reject.
const getUsers = () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(5);
  });
}
const foundUsers = async () => {
  const users = await getUsers();
  return Boolean(users);
}
const LoggedIn = () => {
  const [usersFound, setUsersFound] = useState(false)
  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const found = await foundUsers();
    if (found) {
      //do stuff
    }
    setUsersFound(found)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
      { usersFound ? <Dialog /> : <WhateverElse /> }
    </>
  )
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
const LoggedIn = () => {
  const [usersFound, setUsersFound] = useState(false)
  const onSubmit = () => {
    foundUsers().then((found) => {
      if (found) {
        //do stuff
      }
      setUsersFound(found)
    })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
      { usersFound ? <Dialog /> : <WhateverElse /> }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: the intention is to not execute the rest of the code insde submit button if users were found. How can I do that? That is why I am trying to use the true false here.

Comment: I replaced the answer to something I think better answers what you're asking "how can I return a boolean from a promise". Hopefully this makes more sense.